# Zabbix HP EVA 5000 monitoring

Tags: zabbix, hp

Как можно мониторить HP StorageWorks Enterprise Virtual Array 5000 в zabbix'е?
Гоголь не помогает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно включить SNMP траппер на HP EVA 5000